# Запятая в предложении перед союзом

Tags: сложное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая в предложении перед союзом и?

Я готовлюсь к повышению на случай, если я сделаю хорошо свою работу и он одобрит мою идею.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая **не** нужна.

[Я готовлюсь к повышению на случай], (если я сделаю хорошо свою работу) и (он одобрит мою идею).

"Я готовлюсь к повышению" -- это главное предложение.

"Если я сделаю хорошо свою работу" и "он одобрит мою идею" -- это однородные придаточные. Однородные, потому что к ним задается один, общий вопрос от главного предложения.

[Я готовлюсь к повышению на случай], (если?) (если я сделаю хорошо свою работу) и (если?) (он одобрит мою идею).

При однородных придаточных второй союз можно опустить, поэтому второго "если" нет.

Между однородными придаточными, соединенными сочинительным союзом "и", запятая не ставится. Поэтому запятой перед "и" нет.

Надеюсь, что мой ответ будет полезн :))

Comment: @Nektoid, насколько я знаю, союзы не являются членами предложения, поэтому, по-моему, союз "если" нельзя нельзя назвать общим членом.

Comment: Я имел в виду общий элемент. Некорректно выразился.

Comment: я так и подумала, но решила уточнить, может я в чем-то ошибаюсь :))

Answer (score 1):

**Не нужна**, потому что есть общий член: "если".